# How to print data to a ms word table dynamically in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a `List<String[]>` and I populate that from a CSV file.

```
List<String[]> csvData = ReadCSV.readAll();
```

So I need to put those data into a table that has many rows depending on the CSV list size but there are only 2 columns. So I need to print those data into a word document in the `Zig-Zag` order as follows.

```
_______________________________
|   Data One   |   Data Two   |
_______________________________
|   Data Three |   Data Four  |
_______________________________
|   Data Five  |   Data Six   |
_______________________________
```

So I am a little confused with this how to do this and get two `String[]` data at a time. Because the  `List<String[]>` is like the following,

```
[1st, Data One]
[2nd, Data Two]
[3rd, Data Three]
[4th, Data Four]
```

So I tried to print the data as follows,

```
for (int i = 0; i < csvData.size(); i = i + 2) {
    String[] arrayOne = csvData.get(i);
    String[] arrayTwo = csvData.get(i + 1);

    // Print in word
    table.getRow(i).getCell(0).setParagraph(paragraph that contains arrayOne data);
    table.getRow(i).getCell(1).setParagraph(paragraph that contains arrayTwo data);
}
```

But with this approach, I am getting errors if there is an odd number of data in the CSV file and the `table.getRow(i)` is also not working correctly. I tried with array merging also but didn't work when the CSV list has an odd number of data. So what is the best approach to do what I need? Anybody can help me to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just add an `if` check that only processes arrayTwo if there is an even number of data, maybe somehing like `if(csvData.size() > i+1) String[] arrayTwo = csvData.get(i + 1);`

Comment: @sorifiend I didn't get that. Can you explain me more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table shall have two columns, then it needs `int rows = (int)Math.ceil(csvData.size()/2d);`.

To fill the table you need iterator `r` for rows as well as iterator `c` for columns as well as iterator `i` for iterating the list. There is only a cell value to set if `i < csvData.size()`.

Complete working example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CreateWordTableFromList {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  List<String[]> csvData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  csvData.add(new String[]{"1st", "Data One"});
  csvData.add(new String[]{"2nd", "Data Two"});
  csvData.add(new String[]{"3rd", "Data Three"});
  csvData.add(new String[]{"4th", "Data Four"});
  csvData.add(new String[]{"5th", "Data Five"});
  csvData.add(new String[]{"6th", "Data Six"});
  csvData.add(new String[]{"7th", "Data Seven"});
  //csvData.add(new String[]{"8th", "Data Eight"});

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table");

  int cols = 2;
  int rows = (int)Math.ceil(csvData.size()/2d);
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(rows, cols);
  XWPFTableRow row;
  XWPFTableCell cell;
  int i = 0;
  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
   row = table.getRow(r);
   for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    cell = row.getCell(c);
    if (i < csvData.size()) cell.setText(csvData.get(i)[1]);
    i++;
   }
  }
 
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTableFromList.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, you can avoid the issues with an odd number of data by using an `if` statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < csvData.size(); i = i + 2) {
    String[] arrayOne = csvData.get(i);
    // Print in word
    table.getRow(i).getCell(0).setParagraph(paragraph that contains arrayOne data);

    //Check if the second bit of data in a row exists, otherwise ignore it
    if (csvData.size() > i){
        String[] arrayTwo = csvData.get(i + 1);
        table.getRow(i).getCell(1).setParagraph(paragraph that contains arrayTwo data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I accept the other answer because I needed to get every table row instead of going through 2 by 2. Thank you very much for helping me.